# Как сделать ссылку на место используя яндекс API?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте возникла задача:

У нас есть ссылка на яндекс карту с координатами объекта, при нажатие на эту ссылку должна открываться карта с объектом!

Как организовать такую ссылку?

Comment: В яндексе и организовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

смотрите пример
[пример](http://webmap-blog.ru/files/ymap-modal/index.html)

статья с описанием реализации 
[статья](http://webmap-blog.ru/yandex-maps/vyvodim-yandeks-kartu-v-modalnom-okne#more-1213)

Comment: Обращайте внимание, что на текущий момент данный ответ основан на старой версии API Яндекс.Карт

Comment: так посмотрите на дату ответа

Comment: Я посмотрел перед тем как написать. Это примечание для тех, кто захочет воспользоваться вашим ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Указать ссылку на Яндекс.Карты. При клике откроется веб версия Яндекс.Карт. [Вот документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web-docpage/?from=SO). Пример ссылки:

   ```
   https://yandex.ru/maps/?whatshere[point]=37.444076,55.776788&whatshere[zoom]=17
   ```

   или

   ```
   https://yandex.ru/maps/?pt=30.335429,59.944869&z=18&l=map
   ```
2. Использовать [Геоссылку](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geolink-docpage/?from=SO) из JS API. От вас нужны только координаты, всё остальное API сделает сам. [Пример в песочнице.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolink?from=SO)

   Ссылка и карта будут выглядеть так:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Код ссылки (надо ещё подключить API):

   ```
   <span class="ymaps-geolink">55.778096, 37.562234</span>
   ```
3. Накодить свой попап. Тогда у вас будет простая ссылка в тексте, по клику на которую вы будете открывать карту с любой конфигурацией.